# debian stable raid autogrow filesystem database

Tags: debian, filesystems, database, raid1, btrfs

I need to setup a `debian stable` system meeting the following needs:

- Hard disks should be mirroring : `Raid 1`
- Filesystem(s) should `autogrow` if possible (just in case we replace one hdd with a bigger one, wait until sync and replace the other with a bigger one, too)
- autogrow should work `online`
- the main purpose for the hdd space is holding a `database`

Of course there are several ideas to get that done - but I'm searching for the best.
My feeling at the moment is, that `btrfs` (as there is no real stable `zfs`)  might be the solution - but is it stable enough?
I'm open to and interested in any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend you to use a separate and inexpensive HDD to host the OS (`/`).  The RAID1 HDD (pair) should host only the database file in order to keep the system modular.
2. I've never seen RAID nor Linux filesystem supporting `autogrow`.  You need to manually run a command to extend the filesystem size.  (But there are quite a few filesystems which support extending the size online.)
3. `ext4` on `mdadm` RAID1 would be the most standard option for your requirement.  Both support "grow as much as possible" via command line options.

   - http://kudzia.eu/b/2013/04/installation-of-debian-wheezy-on-mdadm-raid1-gpt/
   - https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing

Comment: Thank you nodakai, I'll wait some time and if no other answers come in, I'll declare your answer as the solution. (Concerning your point 3 - do both support those command line options for `online processing`?)